# Read file contents into string, not string array

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#. I'm trying to store the contents of a text file into a string. I tried the ReadAllLines method but it requires a string[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the

```
File.ReadAllText()
```

You can find more information on the MSDN site

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this.

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadAllText` to read all the content from the text file into a single `string`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you seek:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFile.txt"))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```